# What does "little of substance" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Yet by the end of the year, for reasons both domestic and foreign, Mrs May will have achieved **little of substance**.

Does this mean she will achieve nothing significant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consult Oxford dictionary you will see that:

**[substance](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/substance)**: [mass noun] The quality of being important, valid, or significant.

Interestingly, it provides you with a similar example:

> he had yet to accomplish anything of substance.

So, It think you're right.